# Notify child class property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

Is it possible to notify changes on a child class? Like the way binding on ValueB is notified when changing ValueA?

The PropertyChangedEventHandler only allows a propertyname to be notified.

The only way I see is adding functionality to the Child class to call notification there (Notify method)..

```
public class Parent: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Child ChildA
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Child ChildB
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int ValueA
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueA;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueA = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueA));
        }
    }

    public int ValueB
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueB;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueB = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueA));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueB));
        }
    }

    public void RefreshBindings()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(ChildA.Check);
        OnPropertyChanged(ChildB.Check);
    }
}

public class Child: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void Notify(string property)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(property);
    }

    public bool Check
    {
        get
        {
            return // something;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Child class as well

Comment: If/when you leave the property name empty the whole object is 'refreshed'

Comment: Which property do you bind to in the view?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada it is

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd are you sure?

Comment: @mm8 ChildA.Check / ChildB.Check

Comment: @RalfdeKleine: Then the `Child` class should raise change notifcations for these.

Comment: If `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented, then `Notify(nameof(ChildA.Check));` should work

Comment: @NawedNabiZada: `nameof(ChildA.Check)` is equal to `Check`.

Comment: @mm8 Correct, and since he says INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented, and Notify is a Method of ChildA then it should work

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I'll try that.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I appreciate you suggestions but they do not work. Please only suggest it if you know for a fact they work.

Answer (score 3):

> @NawedNabiZada I appreciate you suggestions but they do not work.
>   Please only suggest it if you know for a fact they work.

Not sure what you tried, but my point is this:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Child A :"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ChildA.Check}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Child B :"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ChildB.Check}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Content="Check/UnCheck" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshBindingCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Parent:

```
public class Parent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Child ChildA
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Child ChildB
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ICommand RefreshBindingCommand { get; }

    public Parent()
    {
        ChildA = new Child(true);
        ChildB = new Child(false);
        RefreshBindingCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshBindingCommand_Execute);
    }

    void RefreshBindingCommand_Execute(object obj)
    {
        RefreshBindings();
    }

    public void RefreshBindings()
    {
        ChildA.Notify(nameof(ChildA.Check));
        ChildB.Notify(nameof(ChildB.Check));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Child:

```
public class Child : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _check;    

    public bool Check
    {
        get
        {
            _check = !_check;
            return _check;
        }
    }

    public Child(bool check)
    {
        _check = check;
    }

    public void Notify(string property)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(property);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Proof that it works:
[image]

Comment: For those who wonder how the binding works, you need to modify your MainWindow.xaml.cs with
`DataContext = new Parent();`

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the *source* of the binding that should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications for the framework to be able to refresh the bindings "automatically".

So if you bind to `ChildA.Check` of `Parent`, it's the object returned by the `ChildA` property (i.e. the `Child` class) that should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The other option would to bind to properties of `Parent` that wraps properties of `Child`, but the `Child` must still somehow notify the parent when its state changes.

Comment: I would really like to use method RefreshBindings to notify changes in the child classes.

Comment: The Check property only has a getter so I will have to notify from somewhere else. The code in my question is a simplified version of my actual code.

Comment: Bind to a wrapper property `X` that returns `ChildA.Check` then and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `X`.

Comment: Yes that would work, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for then? This is how the binding engine works and there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: I am trying to notify property changes in a sub object from the parent object.

Comment: Did you read my answer? This is only possible using wrapper properties since it's the source of the binding that must implement `INPC`.

Comment: I sense some irritation. I'm not here trying to irritate people I'm trying to understand and I'm having some trouble there. I will contemplate your answer and meditate on understanding. Thanks..

Comment: @RalfdeKleine: There is no irriration from my side :) I am just trying to tell you not to bang your head against the wall trying to find a solution that doesn't exist.